# Google's BigQuery api times out before the specified timeout

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

I am using google's BQ api client in Python (googleapiclient) and I have a query that runs for around 10 minutes... when trying to get the results, I can see that I get a response after one minute for a retry that is being done (I have configured 3 retries)

> INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects//queries/?timeoutMs=300000&alt=json
>   WARNING:googleapiclient.http:Sleeping 0.34 seconds before retry 1 of 3 for request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects//queries/?timeoutMs=300000&alt=json, after ('The read operation timed out',)

my code looks like this:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import googleapiclient.discovery

BQ_QUERY_TIMEOUT = 300000
BQ_QUERY_RETRIES = 3

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bigquery = googleapiclient.discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

query_data = {
        'query': query,
        'useLegacySql': use_legacy_sql
    }

query_job = bigquery.jobs().query(projectId=BQ_PROJECT_ID, body=query_data).execute()
    page_token = None
    while True:
        page = bigquery.jobs().getQueryResults(pageToken=page_token, timeoutMs=BQ_QUERY_TIMEOUT, **query_job['jobReference']).execute(num_retries=BQ_QUERY_RETRIES)
        for row in page.get('rows', []):
            yield row
        page_token = page.get('pageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
```

The query times out after **exactly one minute** and then retries, for 3 times, and I can't get the results..

Any thoughts? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you trying running the query using the [cloud-api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/query.py) do you get the same error?

Comment: @WillianFuks No error, but after 30 minutes where it didn't return and nothing happened I aborted..

Comment: you know how many gigas the response has? does it working saving the results to another table instead of bringing to local?

Comment: It's around 300GB and as the documentation states, it saves it to a temporary table.. not local one

Comment: I know it does, what I meant by local is the `yield row` operation which loads results to local memory. If the result is 300 GB then you either have a cluster with 300 GB of memory or it won't be possible to bring this data to your machine.

Comment: I do manage to get results if I raise the amount of retries... but was looking for something more graceful maybe...